# Django How to pre-populate a form field with a argument form context

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I have the following view below. I would like to use '`email`' from the `get_context_data method` to pre-populate a form field in my UserAuthenticationForm form, how is this possible?

View:

```
class CampaignLoginView(LoginView):
    model = Campaign
    form_class = UserAuthenticationForm


    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super(CampaignLoginView, self).get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        user = AppUser.objects.get(pk=1)
        context['email'] = user.email
```

Form:

```
class UserAuthenticationForm(AuthenticationForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(UserAuthenticationForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
```

Or is there is a way 'I should be doing it'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to do is pass `initial` data to the form. Assuming that LoginView is a class-based view that includes the FormMixin, this is best done in the `get_form_kwargs` method:

```
def get_form_kwargs(self):
    kwargs = super(CampaignLoginView, self).get_form_kwargs()
    kwargs['initial']['email'] = self.request.user.email
    return kwargs
```

Comment: Hi Daniel thank you for your response. Just so I'm clear, so this is a function available in my CBV that will allow me to then access the email string in the form init method? i.e could I then just do self.kwargs['user_email'] to get this in the form?

Comment: ok so that actually works, just tested thanks  Daniel. So I take it that somewhere in the CBV it passes this to the form object as I have no idea how it works.

Comment: Sure, you can see from [the code](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/views/generic/edit.py#L10): `get_form` passes the result of `get_form_kwargs` to the form class to instantiate it.